# Multiple simultaneously API calls with Retrofit2 and Flow

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, kotlin-flow

I want to make 2 simultaneous API calls in my app. Currently, in Screen (`@Composable`) I have the following logic:

```kotlin
val (one, setOne) = remember {
    mutableStateOf(
        viewModel.currentOne
    )
}

val (two, setTwo) = remember {
    mutableStateOf(
        viewModel.currentTwo
    )
}

fun initSearch()
{
    setOne(viewModel.call1())
    setTwo(viewModel.call2())
}
```

`call1` and `call2` looks like this:

```kotlin
fun call1(): Flow<String>? { /* */ }

fun call2(): Flow<String>? { /* */ }
```

Now when I run `initSearch` it only calls the first API request which is `call1`. If I change function order and call first `call2` it doesn't call `call1`.

I found these questions:

- [Multiple API calls Simultaneously and update UI as soon as the processing of the corresponding request finishes Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59197609/multiple-api-calls-simultaneously-and-update-ui-as-soon-as-the-processing-of-the)
- [Multiple retrofit2 requests using Flowable in Kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45441074/multiple-retrofit2-requests-using-flowable-in-kotlin)
- [How can I call multiple requests at the same time in Retrofit 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35827090/how-can-i-call-multiple-requests-at-the-same-time-in-retrofit-2/35833851)

but I have no idea how I can use it with `Flow`